# RUSLE K factor tonne conversion to Kg

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

I have a dataset with the RUSLE K factor coming from ESDAC. The K factor is in (t ha h) / (ha Mj mm) This is (tonne * hectare * hour) / (hectare * Megajoule * millimeter)

I am trying to convert this to the following format: (Kg h) / (Mj mm). So it needs to become (Kilogram * hour) / (Megajoule * millimeter)

My question is how i can convert this. I tend to just multiply the K factor with 1000. But i am not sure if this is 'allowed'. What is the correct way of converting? Perhaps the image gives clarification.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSKca.png)

Comment: $\bf{tonne}$ is also known as $\bf{megagram}$. It is also called $\bf{metric\space ton}$. We know that one megagram (Mg) is equal to 1000 killoghrams (Kg). Therefore, there are 1000 kilograms in one tonne (t). Why were you having doubts about your conversion?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i was having doubts since if i multiply it with a 1000. what happens to the millimeter and Megajoule?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those units will change. They both remain the same.

For example, assume that you want to convert and express this $K$ factor in $\small{\dfrac{\text{Kg}\enspace\text{day}}{\text{Kj}\enspace\text{cm}}}$ from its original units $\small{\dfrac{\text{tonne}\enspace\text{hour}}{\text{Megajoule}\enspace\text{mm}}}$.

Then, you would first multiply the value of the $K$ factor by $\bf{1000}$ to make it $\small{\dfrac{\text{Kg}\enspace\text{hour}}{\text{Mj}\enspace\text{mm}
}}$.

Next, you must divide this by $\bf{24}$ to convert it to $\small{\dfrac{\text{Kg}\enspace\text{day}}{\text{Mj}\enspace\text{mm}}}$.

Therafter, in order to get the units changed to $\small{\dfrac{\text{Kg}\enspace\text{hour}}{\text{Kj}\enspace\text{mm}}}$, we have to divide the value of the $K$ factor by $\bf{1000}$.

To complete the conversion of the units to $\small{\dfrac{\text{Kg}\enspace\text{hour}}{\text{Kj}\enspace\text{cm}}}$, multiply it by $\bf{10}$.

Therefore, the conversion factor for this particular case is $1000\times\dfrac{1}{24}\times\dfrac{1}{1000}\times 10=0.41666666666667$.